# Cross-origin request succeeded without CORS

Tags: jquery, ajax, http, xmlhttprequest

This is making me doubt myself now.

We are able to make a POST request via jQuery Ajax. Something like

```
$.post("https://external.com", $('form').serialize());
```

In my Chrome console, I can see the message that says

> XMLHttpRequest cannot load {external.com}. No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'mysite.com' is therefore not allowed access.

In the network tab however, this Ajax call actually returns 200, and of course, the external web service does process my request.

Can anyone shed some light on me, I am going crazy over this...

Many thanks.

Answer (score -1):

I think you may misunderstand the idea of CORS mechanism. If you read the message carefully, you should understand.

> No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.

It says that the **resource** didn't have required header, therefore it's obvious that browser had to make the request first in order to check resource's headers.

> Origin 'mysite.com' is therefore not allowed access.

Also this part says that **you're not allowed** to get the cross-origin resource, while I think you might expected CORS to work as security like to block scripts (e.g. injected by an attacker).

You can read more about CORS [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Access_control_CORS). The important (and tl;dr; ;-) ) part is:

> The Cross-Origin Resource Sharing standard works by adding new HTTP headers that allow servers to describe the **set of origins that are permitted to read** that information using a web browser.

Comment: While CORS mostly protects loading of resources in browser, instead of prevent of downloading, for POST requests (and other requests that can change state) browsers should send a preflight request to get the CORS header, and then if the CORS header is set, it should send the real request. So while I understand that you might see a request in the Network tab (assuming that's the preflight request and if you look a little closer it shouldn't have your POST body details if it is) I don't understand the OP saying this service processed the request - as there should have been no request to process!

Comment: Exactly, I was expecting to see the error message, and didn't expect the external service to process my request. However, I did get the error in the console, AND the request DID reach the external service and got 200 response. Hence my question.

Comment: Since you can set HTTP headers in PHP (or any other server side language), request must be processed, because you don't know what the final headers will be. What if you want to set CQRS header in PHP? From HTTP communication point of view , the resource is the result of the requested service, and not the service itself. Browser doesn't even know if it's static asset of dynamic service.